# how to open fragment class from acivity class

Tags: android

Here is my code from activity

```
Button dialogButton1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    dialogButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SendFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
```

It gives error : have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Fragments Using Intents, Fragments are a part of Activity and you can add, remove or replace Fragment .
Create a FrameLayout in activity layout xml file.

Then do this in your activity to add fragment:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container,YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME,YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```